# Oracle Database Actions. Load data from .csv

Tags: oracle, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I'm trying to load some data from .csv files to my Oracle Autonomous Database using the web interface (Oracle Database Actions)

I get the following error.

"Failed to create error logging table MYSCHEMA.SDW$ERR$_MYTABLE"

I have try to load the data to an existing table and also to a new one.

Looks like is using the LOG ERRORS feature.
https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/dml-error-logging-10gr2
But there is some error with the permissions... but I get the same error using the admin user.

Any ideas about how bypass this problem?

Comment: I never used Oracle Autonomous Database nor its web interface. Though, is there any other message? Maybe error code (ORA-xxxxx)? If so, which one? Also, does user (you're connected to; MYSCHEMA) have CREATE TABLE privilege granted? What is that "admin" user you mentioned? I presume that it isn't SYS (or SYSTEM), right?

Comment: You can see what system privileges the logged-in user has by executing `SELECT * FROM USER_SYS_PRIVS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, looks like a bug of the Oracle Database Actions web interface.

This option from SQL interface not works (as ADMIN)

[image]

Due lack of privileges over SYS as pointed by @Littlefoot

But the same action, with the same .csv and table, also as ADMIN works fine using the "Data Load" option.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a lack of privileges.

I suggest you grant `DWROLE` to `MYSCHEMA`.
This predefined role provides the common privileges needed for a database developer.
You can find more info about it in the [Autonomous Database Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/manage-users-privileges.html#GUID-63669A4D-227E-4C0F-9794-1B2BC4106725).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run datatools, you need additional privilegies.

This is my user creation script:

```
CREATE USER VS IDENTIFIED BY <password>;
GRANT DWROLE TO VS;
GRANT CONNECT TO VS;
GRANT RESOURCE TO VS;
GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO VS;
GRANT SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE TO VS;
BEGIN ORDS_ADMIN.ENABLE_SCHEMA(
     p_enabled => TRUE,
     p_schema => 'VS',
     p_url_mapping_type => 'BASE_PATH',
     p_url_mapping_pattern => 'VS',
     p_auto_rest_auth => TRUE);
    COMMIT;
END;
/
```